# creating unique sequence for October 15 to April 30th following year- R

Tags: r, date, sequence

Basically, I'm looking at snowpack data. I want to assign a unique value to each date (column "snowday") over the period October 15 to May 15th the following year (the winter season of course) ~215 days. then add a column "snowmonth" that corresponds to the sequential months of the seasonal data, as well as a "snow year" column that represents the year where each seasonal record starts.

There are some missing dates- however- but instead of finding those dates and inserting NA's into the rows, I've opted to skip that step and instead go the sequential root which can then be plotted with respect to the "snowmonth"

Basically, I just need to get the "snowday" sequence of about 1:215 (+1 for leap years down in a column, and the rest I can do myself.  It looks like this

```
month day year depth    date yearday snowday snowmonth
  12  26 1955    27 1955-12-26     360      NA        NA
  12  27 1955    24 1955-12-27     361      NA        NA
  12  28 1955    24 1955-12-28     362      NA        NA
  12  29 1955    24 1955-12-29     363      NA        NA
  12  30 1955    26 1955-12-30     364      NA        NA
  12  31 1955    26 1955-12-31     365      NA        NA
   1   1 1956    25 1956-01-01       1      NA        NA
   1   2 1956    25 1956-01-02       2      NA        NA
   1   3 1956    26 1956-01-03       3      NA        NA


man<-data.table()
man <-  read.delim('mansfieldstake.txt',header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
man[is.na(man)]<-0
man$date<-paste(man$yy, man$mm, man$dd,sep="-", collapse=NULL)
man$yearday<-NA #day of the year 1-365
colnames(man)<- c("month","day","year","depth", "date","yearday")

man$date<-as.Date(man$date)
man$yearday<-yday(man$date)
man$snowday<-NA
man$snowmonth<-NA
man[420:500,]
head(man)
```

output would look something like this:

```
month day year depth    date    yearday   snowday   snowmonth
  12  26 1955    27 1955-12-26     360      73        3
  12  27 1955    24 1955-12-27     361      74        3
  12  28 1955    24 1955-12-28     362      75        3
  12  29 1955    24 1955-12-29     363      76        3
  12  30 1955    26 1955-12-30     364      77        3
  12  31 1955    26 1955-12-31     365      78        3
   1   1 1956    25 1956-01-01       1      79        4
   1   2 1956    25 1956-01-02       2      80        4
   1   3 1956    26 1956-01-03       3      81        4
```

I've thought about loops and all that- but it's inefficient... leap years kinda mess things up as well- this has become more challenging than i thought. good first project though!

just looking for a simple sequence here, dropping all non-snow months.  thanks for anybody who's got input!

Comment: Can you show us what you expect the output to look like? It's not exactly clear what you are asking. would `man$snowday <- 1:nrow(man)`?

Comment: man$snowday would be a 1:215 or so sequence from %Y-10-15 to %Y+1-5-15. October to May, every just putting a unique, ordered value to the sequence of the period- this defines the snowday.  this sequence would repeat for each snowyear. from 1955 to 2016. October 15th is the first snowday of the snowyear, and May 15th is the last snowday.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that `snowday` should be the number of days since the beginning of the season, all you need to make this column using `data.table` is:

```
day_one <- as.Date("1955-10-01")
man[, snowday := -(date - day_one)]
```

If all you want is a sequence of unique values, then `seq()` is your best bet.

Then you can create the `snowmonth` using:

```
library(lubridate)
man[, snowmonth := floor(-time_length(interval(date, day_one), unit = "month"))
```

Comment: thanks for this- but I need it to iterate through each snowyear from 1955 until now, and provide the 60 or so 1:215 snowdays for each snowyear.  I guess I'm struggling with the syntax of this- spent a few days trying to get this to work!

Comment: If this is all in one data.table you could create a `day_one` column that has the nearest Oct 1st to the date col and apply the solution above.